# I want to explicitly define a new class object. But how do I specify that I want a list of objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, oop

Say I have a class of people

```
class person()
   def __init__(self, fname:str, lname:str):
      self.fname = fname
      self.lname = lname
```

How do I say that I'm expecting a list of person?

```
class group()
   def __init__(self, groupName:str, people:person|person[]):
      self.groupName = groupName
      self.people = people
```

Could I use ... `people:person|list[person]):` ?

Comment: Why the `person|` part, if you're specifically expecting a list and *not* a `person`?

Comment: My thinking was that there may be some "groups" with only 1 "person". But it makes sense to force a list, as a list can have only 1 item. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A list of `person` objects is `list[person]` (or `typing.List[person]`, prior to Python 3.9).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `people: list[person]` to indicate that the `people attribute` is expected to be a list of person objects. The `|` symbol is not used in this case, because you only want to specify a single type, which is a list of person objects.

```
class group():
   def __init__(self, groupName:str, people:list[person]):
      self.groupName = groupName
      self.people = people
```

When you use the `|` symbol, you are indicating that the attribute can store either one type or another. For example, `person | list[person]` would indicate that the attribute can store either a single person object or a list of person objects.

Comment: This was my original intent. But after reading the comments and thinking it through, I realized that it would be less work to accept a list[object] with 1 item in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
class Person:                                                                                           
    def __init__(self, fname: str, lname: str):                                                         
        self._fname = fname                                                                             
        self._lname = lname                                                                             
                                                                                                        
                                                                                                        
class Group:                                                                                           
    def __init__(self, name: str, people: Person|list[Person]):                                   
        self._name = name                                                                   
        self._people = people
```

and `mypy` will be happy. That said, it's probably a better design to simply have `people: list[Person]` (i.e. only a list is accepted), and have a 1-item list if only one person is in the group. Otherwise, you may have to implement different member functions for different types (or a bunch of `if` branches) if those functions use `self._people`.

Comment: `mypy` may be happy, but you will be severely limited in what you can do with `people` (and by extension, `self._people`), because it will only accept operations that are valid for both `Person` and `list[Person]` objects.

Comment: While this technique may have some drawbacks, there may be some scenarios where using both may be necessary or desired. @JustLearning thanks for your input.